# Error when I try to DIM something as a Chart or ChartObject

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to simply make a graph in VBA but get the error:

user defined type not defined

I've been able to dim it as an object and produce it, but then I can't edit any of its member properties. I'm running VBA from *MS-Access* but I'm unsure that would affect it.

Here's my full code

```
    Dim TATchart As ChartObject
    Set TATchart = wrkSht.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Width:=375, Top:=50, Height:=225)
    With TATchart.Chart
        Set ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        .SetSourceData Source:=wrkSht.Range(wrkSht.cells(1, 1), CurCell.offset(0, 1))
        Set .Title = "Total Over Time (MAW)"
    End With
```

EDIT: wrkSht is initialized as a worksheet and has been working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to `Dim` something `As ChartObject`, you will need to add a reference to your project.  From the VB Editor's main menu, choose Tools->References.  Then scroll down the list until you find *"Microsoft Excel < version > Object Library"* and check the box next to it.

Then your `Dim` should compile.

```vb
Dim TATchart As ChartObject
```

You might prefix it with `Excel` as a reminder where it comes from:

```vb
Dim TATchart As Excel.ChartObject
```

Note you would have encountered a similar compile error at  the *xlXYScatterLines* constant because that is also unknown to Access VBA without the Excel type library reference.